# Postgres: execute a function with condition: CASE WHEN EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to execute this function:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT id
  FROM public.contributor
  WHERE owner = '7d132812-4828-4a48-807c-5f5d7a459447' AND library = '45781650-11d1-4f66-b11b-23a7e761f224'
)
THEN
    UPDATE public.contributor SET commits = contributor.commits + 1 WHERE owner = '7d132812-4828-4a48-807c-5f5d7a459447' AND library = '45781650-11d1-4f66-b11b-23a7e761f224'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO public.contributor (name, commits, image, library, owner)
    SELECT owner_name, 1, owner_image, library, owner FROM public.commit WHERE id = 'e3c8a92a-64c7-408a-baa4-d80f47c3d3c3'
END
```

But it constantly returns syntax errors:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "public"
LINE 7:  UPDATE public.contributor SET commits = contributor.commits...
```

Each one piece of this function works fine separately from each other:
1

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT id
  FROM public.contributor
  WHERE owner = '7d132812-4828-4a48-807c-5f5d7a459447' AND library = '45781650-11d1-4f66-b11b-23a7e761f224'
)
THEN
    true
ELSE
    false
END
```

2

```
UPDATE public.contributor SET commits = contributor.commits + 1 WHERE owner = '7d132812-4828-4a48-807c-5f5d7a459447' AND library = '45781650-11d1-4f66-b11b-23a7e761f224'
```

3

```
INSERT INTO public.contributor (name, commits, image, library, owner)
    SELECT owner_name, 1, owner_image, library, owner FROM public.commit WHERE id = 'e3c8a92a-64c7-408a-baa4-d80f47c3d3c3'
```

Each one of these 3 functions works fine, but together they don't work. Where is my mistake?

May be instead of this structure i should use `ON CONFLICT` operator?

Comment: `CASE WHEN` does not allow you nest arbitrary queries, it is for expressions only. There is no way to conditionally run either an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in pure sql (fortunately)

Comment: @zerkms, thank you! Is there way to do what i tried to do? May be i should use `ON CONFLICT` operator?

Comment: Check the second half of my comment.

Comment: There is `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` operator since 9.5 version. Read docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: Right, well, if it fits the use case - then sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO public.contributor (name, commits, image, library, owner)
    SELECT owner_name, 1, owner_image, library, owner FROM public.commit WHERE id = 'e3c8a92a-64c7-408a-baa4-d80f47c3d3c3' ON CONFLICT (owner, library) DO UPDATE SET commits = (contributor.commits + 1)
```